# Is there a way to design neural networks with symmetric Jacobians?

Tags: neural-networks, reference-request

Is there a way to design neural networks with *symmetric Jacobians*-the Jacobian of the output with respect to the input? Could you point me to any relevant literature in this area?

Comment: While Im not sure to have any pointers to the specific literatures on the topic, it sounds rather challenging. You can take a look at the document here  https://princeton-introml.github.io/files/ch11.pdf for general information on back propagation. The document touches on the jacobians also, so it might be useful.